# Filter section with x-overflow scroll does not display properly

Tags: css, laravel, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am running into a problem using x-overflow.

On large screens I want to create the following:

[I want to create the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNcIH.png)

I currently have however:

[What I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYDUa.png)

My code is as follows:

```
<!-- Filter Section -->
<div class="mx-auto mt-6 p-4 bg-white flex items-center space-x-4 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-white max-w-screen-xl">

    <!-- Categories -->
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
        <span class="font-medium text-gray-600 dark:text-white">Categories:</span>
        
        <div class="relative" x-data="{ openCategories: false }">
            <!-- Mobile Dropdown Button -->
            <button @click="openCategories = !openCategories" class="block md:hidden px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded hover:border-blue-500 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
                Choose
            </button>
            
            <!-- Dropdown Content for Mobile -->
            <div class="absolute z-10 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg md:hidden" x-show="openCategories" @click.away="openCategories = false">
                <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                    <!-- Categories for Mobile -->
                    <button class="block w-full text-left px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900">Architecture</button>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Display for Larger Screens -->
            <div class="flex space-x-4 pb-2 md:block hidden">
                <!-- Categories for Larger Screens -->
                <button class="px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded hover:border-blue-500 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">Architecture</button>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Spacer for visual separation -->
    <div class="mx-4 border-l h-6"></div>

    <!-- Model Slider -->
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
        <span class="font-medium text-gray-600 dark:text-white">Model:</span>
        
        <div class="relative" x-data="{ openModel: false }">
            <!-- Mobile Dropdown Button -->
            <button @click="openModel = !openModel" class="block md:hidden px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded hover:border-blue-500 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
                Choose
            </button>

            <!-- Dropdown Content for Mobile -->
            <div class="absolute z-10 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg md:hidden" x-show="openModel" @click.away="openModel = false">
                <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                    <!-- Models for Mobile -->
                    <button class="block w-full text-left px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900">Midjourney</button>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Display for Larger Screens -->
            <div class="flex space-x-4 pb-2 md:block hidden">
                <!-- Models for Larger Screens -->
                <button class="px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded hover:border-blue-500 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">Architecture</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Spacer for visual separation -->
    <div class="mx-4 border-l h-6"></div>

    <!-- oggle -->
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-2 ml-auto">
        <div class="relative w-6 h-3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="hidden" disabled>
            <div class="bg-gray-300 w-6 h-3 rounded-full"></div>
            <div class="toggle__dot absolute top-0.5 left-0.5 w-2 h-2 bg-white rounded-full"></div>
        </div>
        <label for="toggle" class="flex items-center space-x-1 text-gray-600 dark:text-white">
            <span>Toggle</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anyone could spot the issue please let me know! Kindest of regards.

I expected it to turn out as in the first image, however, it either looks like the first image but without a working mobile menu or vice versa...